# Bulkcopy data from CSV file to PostgreSQL database using C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, csv, amazon-s3

I have a CSV file with data that I need to copy to a table in Postgres database up on the cloud.
Can I do it from C# console app? If I can, what's the syntax? Everything I found so far doesn't give me a clear example how to make the call from C#. In my app I'm using DSN connection (PostgreSQL ODBC driver) to the Postgres database. The CSV file could be either local or in S3 bucket.

Here is my code ( simplified a little):

```
string filePath = "C:\Bluh\Data.CSV";
string sql = string.Format("COPY {0}.{1} FROM '{2}' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ", postgres_catalog, stagingTableName, filePath);
using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sql))
{
   OdbcConnection SQLConn = new OdbcConnection(DBConnectionString);
   SQLConn.Open();
   sc.Connection = SQLConn;
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

When I use the above code I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR [42501] ERROR: must be superuser or a member of the pg_read_server_files role to COPY from a file;
```

If I can't use COPY command on a local file, how can I specify path to that file in S3 bucket? What's the syntax?

Cheers!

Comment: `ERROR [42501] ERROR: must be superuser or a member of the pg_read_server_files role to COPY from a file;` Have you added yourself as a superuser? Does that fix it?

Comment: `COPY` runs as the server user. So the file it is reading needs to be accessible by that user and the database user running the command needs file reading privileges e.g. be a superuser, or a member of role with those privileges. See here [Copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) in **Notes** section for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found and what worked for me

```
        string sql = "SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3('SCHEMA.TABLENAME','COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B', '(FORMAT CSV, HEADER True)', aws_commons.create_s3_uri('S3-Bucket-Name', 'FileName.csv', 'awsRegion'))";

        using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sql))
        {
            ExecuteNonQuery(command);
        }
```

Make sure the account that you use in DSN has sufficient privileges.

Also note that the file name is case sensitive including extension